# Add new element to XML via XSLT 1.0 but without xmlns

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I have this XML file and I've applied an XSLT. The result I want is to add a new element but one that doesn't contain a namespace.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  <ITIN3 />
<Export xmlns="http://www.ibm.com/maximo" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
creationDateTime="2018-09-29T12:53:10+02:00" transLanguage="EN" baseLanguage="EN" 
messageID="24242525" maximoVersion="7 6 20190514-1348 V7611-365" event="1">
<MRCSet>
  <MRC action="Add">
     <PONUM>MPO15114</PONUM>
     <POREVISIONNUM>0</POREVISIONNUM>      
  </MRC>
</MRCSet>
</Export>
```

I have applied this XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"   
 xmlns:mea="http://www.ibm.com/maximo" exclude-result-prefixes="mea">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="no" indent="yes" encoding="UTF-8"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
 
   <!-- Identity transform -->
   <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
     <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>

   </xsl:copy> 
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="/mea:Export/mea:MRCSet/mea:MRC">
   <xsl:copy>
 
   <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
   <NEWINFO>1</NEWINFO>
   <xsl:copy-of select="node()"/>

    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  </xsl:stylesheet>
```

And the result is the one below. But I dont want to have that namespace xmlns. I just want a new element as I wrote it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Export xmlns="http://www.ibm.com/maximo"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        creationDateTime="2018-09-29T12:53:10+02:00"
        transLanguage="EN"
        baseLanguage="EN"
        messageID="24242525"
        maximoVersion="7 6 20190514-1348 V7611-365"
        event="1">
   <MRCSet>
  <MRC action="Add">
     <NEWINFO xmlns="">1</NEWINFO >
     <PONUM>MPO15114</PONUM>
     <POREVISIONNUM>0</POREVISIONNUM>
      </MRC>
   </MRCSet>
</Export>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `xmlns="http://www.ibm.com/maximo"` to the `xsl:stylesheet` element or at least to the `NEWINFO` element.

Comment: Thank you. But can you explain me why is that?

Comment: Your input has elements in the namespace `http://www.ibm.com/maximo` and it seems you want to add an element in that namespace. Your attempt adds an element in no namespace which results in the `xmlns=""` in the result.

Comment: Thx! I understand now

Answer (score 0):

You are analyzing the situation incorrectly:

All the elements of your source document are in the default namespace `xmlns="http://www.ibm.com/maximo"` and your stylesheet copies them *as is*.

Your added element is is no-namespace - and the `xmlns=""` declaration is an indication of that.